# My Like Box with the light color scheme is transparent

Tags: colors, facebook-likebox

I inserted a like box into my site being developed and I'm shocked to see that my like box is transparent:

This code is generated with the "official" likebox code generator. It seems odd to me that there's nothing related to color scheme in this snippet. I inserted `colorscheme="light"` but the like box is still transparent.

Here is the site under construction where you can see the problem online: http://dev.csaladterapia.hu/

Here is a screenshot about the problem:
[image]

Comment: Am I correct in saying that everything on your site is transparent?

Comment: Everything..? No. Have you visited the site?

Comment: Just did. Nothing loads. Nothing is appearing but empty boxes

Comment: Shocked to hear that. The site shows up to me either in FF or Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `light` color scheme seems to have a "transparent" background color set. I'm not sure if this can be set from Facebook side, but why don't you just set the containing `<p>` tag color to `#FFFFFF`?
[image]